# Can't assign array of objects to array of union types in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm learning Flow and therefore I'm working on a little hobby project with JavaScript and Flow. I have a class `Foo` and a different class `Bar` that I want to take in an array of `Foo` objects as an option in the constructor. However, I also want to be able to send some other data for each such object, and so I want to have an array where each element is either a plain `Foo` object, or a `Foo` object wrapped in an array or object.

However, when I tried to write the code for this, I got some weird errors that I don't understand the reason for. As far as I can tell, it thinks that there's a type conflict because `Foo` isn't compatible with *all* of the types of the union, but as far as I understand it should only have to be compatible with at least one of them...

Here's the minimal code I needed to reproduce the exact errors I got ([link to Try Flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDG0CGBnToBitZQBvUAX2QEsA7AFwFMAnSdFO0AIXQYHkAHGirCo4iiUKEgFMALlAAKPAVAAfUAG1FhALoriEgrPyFSoAJRqtAbnE3b4kKGjU2ANkTlUGbBy7ExoFCFMGgYAVxQaWAY5WH5BYQB+WU4eOKDTPXIPQOEafVhDJQBeUCo6eE05U0tkHODQACNfErKKlLlRcUlYGXV80C0AGjsR0bHx0AcnMtAARjdSaqA)):

```js
// @flow

class Foo { }

interface BarOptions {
  foos: ( Foo | [ Foo ] | { foo: Foo } )[];           // line 6
}

class Bar {
  constructor(options?: BarOptions) { }
}

const foo: Foo = new Foo();

const bar = new Bar({
  foos: [ foo ],                                    // line 16
});
```

I get the following errors:

```
Line 6:
  tuple type: This type is incompatible with Foo
  object type: This type is incompatible with Foo
Line 16:
  tuple type: This type is incompatible with Foo
  object type: This type is incompatible with Foo
```

Is there a intuitive (or unintuitive) reason for these errors?

Answer (score 3):

Do you think it might be related to this open Github [ticket](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1569)? If we replace `interface` with `type`, it validates:

```
// @flow

class Foo { }

type BarOptions ={
  foos: 
        Class<Foo> |
        Foo |
        Foo[] |
        { foo: Foo } 
}

class Bar {
  constructor(options?: BarOptions) { }
}

const foo: Foo = new Foo();

const bar = new Bar({
  foos: Foo,
//   foos: foo,
//   foos: [foo],
//   foos: { foo: foo },
});
```

Comment: Can you explain this would work? (My question isn't how to fix it, it's trying to understand why this is a problem in  the first place)

Comment: I fail to see how the two are different; as I have understood it, in both cases `foo` will be declared with the same type (`Foo`), the only difference is that in your first line the type is implicit while in the second it's explicit. Unless I have horribly misunderstood how flow types work, I don't see the how these would behave differently (although it does indeed seem that they do).

Comment: Could this problem be related to this? https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1569

Answer (score 2):

I think `BarOptions` should actually be a type alias instead of an interface. An interface [declares a type that classes can implement](https://flowtype.org/docs/syntax.html#interface-declarations). Interfaces are not data types and they should not have fields (containing data).

Here everything works if we just change `interface BarOptions` to `type BarOptions =`.

Alternatively you can change `foo` to become a getter function:

```
interface BarOptions {
  foos(): ( Foo | [ Foo ] | { foo: Foo } )[];
}
```